# Populate three highchart graphics with one ajax call

Tags: ajax, highcharts

I am trying to figure out how to combine 3 ajax call into 1 but so far I didn't find out the correct way to do it. I have the following three highcharts:

```
chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    height: 155,
                    renderTo: 'chart1_div',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                    events: {
                        load: GetData1(date)
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        fillOpacity: 0.1
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: c,
                    labels: {
                        staggerLines: 2
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    gridLineColor: "#ffffcc",
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    labels: {
                        x: 15,
                        y: 15,
                        style: {
                            color: "#999999",
                            //fontWeight: "bold",
                            fontSize: "10px"
                        }
                    },
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Chart1',
                    color: "#6bd9ec", //37f312
                    data: chart1_data
                }]
            });


chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        height: 155,
                        renderTo: 'chart2_div',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                        events: {
                            load: GetData2(date)
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            fillOpacity: 0.1
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: c,
                        labels: {
                            staggerLines: 2
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        gridLineColor: "#ffffcc",
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        labels: {
                            x: 15,
                            y: 15,
                            style: {
                                color: "#999999",
                                //fontWeight: "bold",
                                fontSize: "10px"
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Chart2',
                        color: "#6bd9ec", //37f312
                        data: chart2_data
                    }]
                });


chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            height: 155,
                            renderTo: 'chart3_div',
                            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                            events: {
                                load: GetData3(date)
                            }
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                fillOpacity: 0.1
                            }
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: c,
                            labels: {
                                staggerLines: 2
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            gridLineColor: "#ffffcc",
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            },
                            labels: {
                                x: 15,
                                y: 15,
                                style: {
                                    color: "#999999",
                                    //fontWeight: "bold",
                                    fontSize: "10px"
                                }
                            },
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Chart3',
                            color: "#6bd9ec", //37f312
                            data: chart3_data
                        }]
                    });
```

At the moment I am making three different ajax calls:

```
function GetData1(date) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/GetAjaxCall',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ date: date }),
                success: function (f) {
                    var cat= [];
                    var ser= [];
                    $.each(f.d, function (i, e) {
                        cat.push(e.date);
                        ser.push(parseInt(e.val1));
                    });
                    chart1_div.xAxis[0].setCategories(cat);
                    chart1_div.series[0].setData(ser);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(e.statusText);
                },
                cache: false
            });
        }

function GetData2(date) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/GetAjaxCall',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ date: date }),
                    success: function (f) {
                        var cat= [];
                        var ser= [];
                        $.each(f.d, function (i, e) {
                            cat.push(e.date);
                            ser.push(parseInt(e.val2));
                        });
                        chart2_div.xAxis[0].setCategories(cat);
                        chart2_div.series[0].setData(ser);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert(e.statusText);
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
            }

function GetData3(date) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/GetAjaxCall',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ date: date }),
                    success: function (f) {
                        var cat= [];
                        var ser= [];
                        $.each(f.d, function (i, e) {
                            cat.push(e.date);
                            ser.push(parseInt(e.val3));
                        });
                        chart3_div.xAxis[0].setCategories(cat);
                        chart3_div.series[0].setData(ser);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert(e.statusText);
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
            }
```

As you can see, I am right now making the same ajax call 3 times just to be able to populate the 3 charts differently. Does anyone know how could I generate exactly the same 3 charts but only make 1 ajax call? Thanks a lot

Something like:

```
function GetDataAll(date) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/GetAjaxCall',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ date: date }),
                    success: function (f) {
                        var cat1= [];
                        var ser1= [];
                        var cat2= [];
                        var ser2= [];
                        var cat3= [];
                        var ser3= [];
                        $.each(f.d, function (i, e) {
                            cat1.push(e.date);
                            ser1.push(parseInt(e.val1));
                        });
                        chart1_div.xAxis[0].setCategories(cat1);
                        chart1_div.series[0].setData(ser1);
                        chart2_div.xAxis[0].setCategories(cat2);
                        chart2_div.series[0].setData(ser2);
                        chart3_div.xAxis[0].setCategories(cat3);
                        chart3_div.series[0].setData(ser3);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert(e.statusText);
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
            }
```

Under the load event I could call GetData1(date) for the 3 charts but this way I will be hitting the ajax call 3 times. I am probably doing this the wrong way and must be a more efficient way. I will appreciate any thoughts, thank you so much

**EDITED - LATEST UPDATE THAT WORKS BASED ON @WERGELD HELP**

```
var chart1_options = { 
    chart: {
           renderTo: 'chart1_div',
    xAxis: {
           categories: []
    },
    series: [{
           name: 'Chart1',
           color: "#6bd9ec"
           }]
    };

var chart2_options = { 
    chart: {
           renderTo: 'chart2_div',
    xAxis: {
           categories: []
    },
    series: [{
           name: 'Chart2',
           color: "#6bd9ec"
           }]
    };

var chart3_options = { 
    chart: {
           renderTo: 'chart3_div',
    xAxis: {
           categories: []
    },
    series: [{
           name: 'Chart3',
           color: "#6bd9ec"
           }]
    };

function GetDataAll(date) {
$ajax({..

                        chart1_options.xAxis.categories = cat1;
                        chart1_options.series[0].data = ser1;

                        chart2_options.xAxis.categories = cat2;
                        chart2_options.series[0].data = ser2;

                        chart3_options.xAxis.categories = cat3;
                        chart3_options.series[0].data = ser3;

                        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(Highcharts.merge(options, chart1_options));
                        var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart(Highcharts.merge(options, chart2_options));
                        var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart(Highcharts.merge(options, chart3_options));

});
}
```

Comment: Creating the series.data in the ajax call for all three charts is the way to do it. Set your chart options (with no data) before the ajax call. Then inside the ajax call you create the actual chart from the data. Remove the `chart.events.load` and just have the ajax call create the chart with the data already present.

Comment: Thanks a lot @wergild, I have removed the chart.events.load but now I get all the charts empty, how can I load the data into the charts? I am calling the ajax function when I load the html page GetDataAll(date) but the data doesn't show :(

Comment: Because you have rendered your chart already so calling the ajax does nothing. I am working on stripped down demo.

Comment: true :(, sorry thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some psuedo code to get you going. What you need to do is setup a chart option object that contains all the constant items among your charts:

```
  var options = {
    chart: {
      height: 155,
      defaultSeriesType: 'spline'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        fillOpacity: 0.1
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: c,
      labels: {
        staggerLines: 2
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineColor: "#ffffcc",
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      labels: {
        x: 15,
        y: 15,
        style: {
          color: "#999999",
          //fontWeight: "bold",
          fontSize: "10px"
        }
      },
    }
  };
```

Next you do your ajax call and assign your series' data and title (and any other items) and create an object for each chart you want to create:

```
var chartOptions1 = {
    chart: { renderTo: 'container1' },
    series: []
};

var chartOptions2 = {
    chart: { renderTo: 'container1' },
    series: []
};
```

Next you do your code to get the chart data/name/etc that you want to have for each chart which I will not go into here. The next step is to then create your chart from the merged options:

```
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(Highcharts.merge(options, chartOptions1));
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart(Highcharts.merge(options, chartOptions2));
```

This should do it. Again, it is psuedocode but you get the idea. Global options + `merge` are you friends. Full psuedocode [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jv4uq9t/).

Comment: Thanks  a billion @wergeld, you are a star :). I've got the idea and working on this right now and will comment back shortly

Comment: I managed to get it to work now thanks to your tremendous help. Thank you so much again and Happy New Year 2017! G-d bless you! - I just updated my post with the code that solves the problem in case it helps someone else. Ah, to make it dynamic before I used to call setTimeout(GetDataAll(date),3000); but now I cannot do that because when I do that it refreshes all the lines too fast and I cannot be able to see the full line anymore. Is there a setting to tell highchart not to clear the chart before refreshing? Thanks again.

Comment: @carol1287, so you want to update the data based upon an ajax call as well as initially loading the chart from an ajax call? This is doable. You will need to change the code to instead of re-creating the whole chart to instead just do a series update of data (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData) or add a new point to the data (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.addPoint). Depends on what you need to have happen.